# position a viewstub programmatically

Tags: android, viewstub

i want to position a viewstub inside a viewgroup pogrammatically.
i tried using the setLayoutParams() method but its not available for viewstubs.
Please suggest any solution.

below is my code.

```
setContentView(R.layout.textplay);
bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                panel = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.serachViewStub2);
                panel.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.half_screen,null);
                panel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
                panel.setOnInflateListener(new OnInflateListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInflate(ViewStub arg0, View arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        parentLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.stubLayout1);
                        parentLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 300));

            }
        });
                    }
        });
```

halfscreen.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/stubLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp" android:weightSum="100"
    android:padding="2dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:background="@color/white">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="10"
        android:hint="Search Location" android:paddingTop="2dp">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <Button android:id="@+id/search_button" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="90"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_search_button">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

textplay.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp" android:paddingRight="25dp" android:background="@drawable/back2">
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:hint="Type a Command">
        <requestFocus></requestFocus>
    </EditText>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="90"
            android:text="Try Command"></Button>
        <ToggleButton android:text="ToggleButton" android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:layout_weight="10"></ToggleButton>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Invalid"
        android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center"></TextView>
<ViewStub android:id="@+id/serachViewStub2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inflatedId="@+id/search_stub"
            android:layout="@layout/half_screen">
        </ViewStub>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you inflate the ViewStub, you can access the layout which the ViewStub is actually showing. Get a reference to the layout and setLayoutparameters on it.

ViewStub inflates my_layout.xml which contains a LinearLayout with id as mainContainer.
Once you inflate the viewstub, get a reference to the mainContainer and apply layout parameters on it.

Comment: Thank you dcanh121 but i'm still not able to position the viewstub. I've included the code.Please refer and suggest me any corrections.

Answer (score 1):

suppose your `ViewStub` is under a `RelativeLayout` container, you can use the following code to set the layout parameters.

```
View view = ((ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.view_stub)).inflate();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
params.bottomMargin = 0;
params.topMargin = 50;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have try methods,the following would be work:
After inflate the viewstub,you can get the viewstub's layout by its id,then its position could be set as you want.

```
//mViewStub is the viewstub
mViewStub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//view is parent of viewstub,
View viewstublayout = view.findViewById(R.id.viewstub_layout);
if (viewstublayout != null) {
    viewstublayout.layout(l, t, r, b);
}
```

fyi